# How to parse date to EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy format?

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am getting date from database as `2013-05-03 00:20:29.0`. I want to parse the date to `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format, but when I am parsing it, I am getting this exception:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-05-03 00:20:29.0"`

My code is below:

```
    String createdDate = "2013-05-03 00:20:29.0";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date parseDate = format.parse(createdDate);
```

Comment: Your format String 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' does not fit to your `createDate` format! Looks more like 'yyyy-MM-ss HH:mm:ss' and a '.0' appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern does not match `createdDate`. The format should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: i have question, when iam saving the date in EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy format, it is saving as 2013-05-03 00:38:20.0, what could be the reason, the same date iam trying to retrieve and display

Comment: Would have to see how it is being saved to answer that question. I suspect you are using the Date object itself when saving. In that case the format will always be that pattern. This is pattern used by `Date#toString`...

Answer (score 7):

You have to adjust the Format pattern. Format must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

As I understod you want to convert your date to a new format

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse("2013-05-03 00:20:29.0");
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").format(date);
```

You can also try to get the date from the DB not as String but as java.sql.Date then the first step will be unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
String str_date= "29/02/2013";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");        
java.util.Date dt = sdf.parse(str_date);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
System.out.println(df.format(dt));
```