# Convert date to other format in JodaTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, converters, jodatime

I've a problem to convert a data in Java using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.
Pratically, the input date have this format:

```
Mon Apr 28 18:57:42 CEST 2014
```

I would like to see this output:

```
2014-04-28
```

I've tried this code, but doesn't works:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf_out = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTimeFormatter dtf_inp = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    String a = String.valueOf(dtf_inp.parseDateTime(String.valueOf(resultsJs.get(0).getTimestamp()))); //crash here
    String b = String.valueOf(dtf_out.parseDateTime(a));
```

Note: `resultsJs.get(0).getTimestamp()` is a Date format.

Instead, this is the log:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon Apr 28 18:57:42 CEST 2014"
            at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
...
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What is the crash message?  Are you sure that resultsJs.get(0) returns something?

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b thanks for reply! Sorry for incomplete post, I've edited the main post. Anyway, resultsJs.get(0) is correct. He doesn't returns null or similar! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse date to EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345711/how-to-parse-date-to-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse an epoch millisecond value, but you can only parse a String.

However, it seems you already have a millisecond value available, so only the formatting is required, which is via the `print()` method:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf_out = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String b = dtf_out.print(resultsJs.get(0).getTimestamp().getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks! But but the print() method accept a Long value input. Can I parse from Date to Long?

Comment: No need to parse - see latest edit, which uses the `getTime()` method of `Date` (I wasn't sure what type was returned from `getTimestamp()`)

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!! :) I prefer this solution because I've solved my problem with 1 row. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine after removing timezone info from the actual string but I have used time zone while parsing hence it will give you the correct result based on locale.

Please validate the result.

```
// pattern zzz is removed that is used for parsing time zone
DateTimeFormatter dtf_inp = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");

// time zone is added while parsing date time
DateTime dateTime = dtf_inp.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris"))
                                   .parseDateTime("Mon Apr 28 18:57:42 2014");

// simply call toString(pattern) on DateTime
System.out.println(dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // 2014-04-28
```

Comment: Thanks! I've solved with @Bohemian 's solution.
Anyway, I'm surprised me too...In fact, in the doc there is this text: 
Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String output = sdf.format(yourDate);
```

Comment: OP is using the Joda classes.